# What are some server side functions that runs before page rendering without returning props in Next.Js?

Tags: next.js

I have a page that does a pre-render check on the user's authorization to a page. If the user is not authorized to view the page, I redirect the user to a 403 forbidden page. This is all done in `getServerSideProps` method. This is all I need, I don't need to return and pass any props to the page component. However, `getServerSideProps` needs to return at least one prop to the page component.

Is there an alternative in which I can check the authorization of the users without returning props to the page component? In other words, Is there a server side function that runs before page rendering and does not return anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just return an empty object.

```
return {
    props: {}
}
```